# Reflection to find classes that implement interface with multiple open generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's say I have an interface like this:

```
public interface ITest<T1, T2>
{
}
```

And a class like this:

```
public class Concrete : ITest<int, string>
{
}
```

Using reflection, how can I find this concrete class?  I've tried the following but it doesn't work because I'm not specifying the generic type parameters.

```
var concretes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Concrete)).GetTypes()
                        .Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ITest<,>))
                               && !x.IsInterface);
```

This returns zero items.  Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var concretes =
    Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof (Concrete))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t =>
        t.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(i =>
            i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITest<,>)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes!  I think this is it!